# What is the difference between “AI Methods” and “AI Techniques”?

Tags: terminology

These are words that we frequently come upon. What can be said about the differences? Would these two words' subheadings be different?

Comment: To answer this question, we need more context. Where did you find these terms? It's possible that they are synonymous, but it's also possible that they are not being used interchangeably. In other words, I don't think that this is standard terminology.

Answer (score 0):

According to webster they are considered synonyms. However, from an academic viewpoint there is a distinction:

A method is a systematic procedure, technique, or mode of inquiry employed by or proper to a particular discipline (e.g. scientific method)

A technique is the manner in which technical details are treated or a way of accomplishing a desired aim that may not be considered a scientific method (e.g. heuristic technique)

Comment: I suggest that you drop "technique" from the second paragraph.

Comment: @codecyher Can we say that "The method has been accepted scientifically, the technique is not generally or scientifically accepted, but it is a solution that works most of the time". For example, shaking a non-working device hard.